# Google Sheet - Return data based on the closest past dates of a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have the following array on Google Sheets :

| Task name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Task 1 | 10/08/2022 |
| Task 2 | 10/08/2022 |
| Task 3 | 05/08/2022 |
| Task 4 | 10/10/2022 |
| Task 5 | 11/11/2022 |
| Task 6 | 20/11/2022 |
| Task 7 | 10/12/2022 |
| Task 8 | 20/12/2022 |
| Task 9 | 02/07/2022 |
| Task 10 | 01/06/2022 |

I am trying to get the 5 closest past dates from the current day TODAY() in colum B. Then, I need to return the corresponding task names. Some dates are identical.

In this case, it would return : Task 1, Task 2, Task 3, Task 9, Task 10.

I've tried using a combination of different formulas with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(A1:B10,"select * order by B limit 5")
```

[image]

Or `FILTER()` like-

```
=FILTER(A1:A10,B1:B10<TODAY())
```

To show all result in a single cell use `JOIN()` function.

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(A1:A10,B1:B10<TODAY()))
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** Best would be using single `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"select A where B <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' order by B DESC limit 5")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In your example with the FILTER() function, how can I limit the results to the 5 closest past dates, please ? My list has hundreds of elements that match the filter and they are all returned

Comment: Try `=QUERY(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A1:B12,B1:B12<=TODAY()),2,1),,1),"limit 5")`.

Comment: Best option would be use `QUERY()` function like `=QUERY(A1:B12,"select A where B <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' order by B DESC limit 5").